# What makes my phone's browser (webkit) go to google?

Tags: android, url, web, mobile, browser

When I key in a URL into my old HTC browser (android 2.2.1) sometimes it goes to the website address properly, but recently it's been going to google, and setting up as if I had asked for a google search.  As an example -

```
www.google.com/m?hl=en&gl=gb&client=ms-android-htc&source=android-browser-goto&q=outer.space
```

("Outer.space" is just a fictitious example.) Certain websites it goes straight to the website, others it does a sort of double-take and goes to google.  I have ascertained on a laptop that all URLs are valid existing websites.  Anybody know why this is happening?  With one URL, it was going to it properly last week, and this week going to google.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. (And I should point out this is just on my cellphone.  My laptop goes to the websites just fine.)

Answer (score 0):

While I was searching on the internet for an answer to this question I found "How to stop search suggestions" - which is similar in that a list of links from google are in fact 'search suggestions'.  And it sounded plausible -

> In the screen full of Apps tap the Google Search app ('g' on blue
>   background).
>       Then tap 'Menu', then 'Search settings'.
>       Under the 'Web' heading choose 'Google search', uncheck 'Show web suggestions'

However this doesn't actually work in HTC Wildfire Android 2.2.1 Webkit 3.1.
When you uncheck the box it has no effect, both the google search page still comes up with suggestions, and so does the browser.

However, thru trial and error, I found how to stop it from linking to a google search (when you are just tapping in to the address bar and don't want it to do a search because you know the website name you want.)

**Just put http:// before the domain name.**

I hope this helps someone.